# Upgrading laptop from SATA 2 to SATA 3

Tags: laptop, ssd, sata, sony-vaio

I'm trying to upgrade my Sony Vaio Fit Laptop with a SATA 3 SSD. My laptop however can only support up to SATA 2. Is there a feasible way of upgrading SATA 2 to SATA 3? I know SATA 3 is backwards compatible but I want to utilize a new SSD to its maximum potential.

Thanks,

Comment: No, not without replacing the motherboard, which is infeasible with most laptops. If you can find a motherboard for that model of laptop's chasis there is a slim possibility that you can swap it out (its quite difficult but doable on many models of laptop), but thats a lot of if's. you may be introducing incompatibilities with existing components like the screen, RAM, audio, wifi, etc. All that said, Sata3 disks are backward compatible with Sata2 buses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SATA controller on your laptop is part of the motherboard. Yes, your new SSD will work, but at SATA-II speeds (3 gbps). I have run SSDs in SATA-II ports before and although you do not get the full SATA-III experience (6 gbps), they are still faster and more reliable than traditional hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

If you have USB 3.0 IT IS possible the only thing what you Need is USB 3 to SATA 3 Adapter If you dont have USB 3.0 you Need an USB 3.0 controller

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help]. I can see from your public profile that you have not taken the tour yet.